# How to replace spaces with dash and remove some characters?

Tags: php, str-replace

How do I replace spaces with dashes **and** remove some characters in a single operation?

The code below works perfectly but requires separate operations; how do I merge them?

```
$_POST[url]=str_replace(str_split('\\/:*?"<>|.,;'), '', $_POST[title]);
$_POST[url]=str_replace(" ","-",$id.'-'.$_POST[title].'.html');
```

Comment: And the problem now is?

Comment: Why do you want to do it in just one step? If you want this part of the code to look cleaner, I'd make a function that takes an input, does both of those steps, and then returns the "cleaned up" string you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`preg_replace` will do the job for you:

```
preg_replace(array('/[\\/:\*\?"<>|\.,;]+/', '/\s/'), array('', '-'), 'Strange string.');
```

Check out some [manuals](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) for help.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')' in xxxxxxxxxx\editor_pages.php on line 57

Comment: oh sorry, ure nor using php 5.5. Try it now.